# In Javascriptcore, question about clobberWorld(), read(World)/write(Heap) and some terminologies

Tags: webkit, javascriptcore

I currently analyze JavaScriptCore's code base.
I know that `clobberWorld()` stand for notifying current operation is effectful.
But, some article says that `read(World)` and `write(Heap)` do same thing as `clobberWorld()`.
What `read()` and `write()` means? And what `World` and `Heap` means?

Last question is about terminologies.
In DFG, what is the full name of `AI` and `CSE`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AI means AbstractInterpreter and CSE means Common SubExpression Elimination. As for read and write, it models a DFG IR node and representing side effect, and in LICM phase you can see it more.